# Mobile filtering data with different views

Tags: mobile, filter, maps

I'm trying to design an app with a map and user added photos.
I want to be able to show data with different views and in the same time i want to be able to toggle all or only current user content.

Views: Map view, List view, Only photos view
Trigger: all, only user's

How can i combine them in one view?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the user content? Are there other types of contents besides photos? It'll help to have a bit more context/mockups on the app you are designing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like filter buttons, grouping them separately and giving more space for those which are pressed more frequently. Location and difference in shapes give clues of different meaning.

[image]

Comment: I end up with something like that, but the filter is on the top of the screen and the view-change buttons are at the bottom. It's kind of okey :)